# Connect client to Node.js server with HTTP(S)

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, client, httprequest

Users 'gather' data on their local pc, and they need to be able to upload it to the server.

I setup a simple node.js server like this:

```
var https = require('https');
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('key.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('cert.pem')
};


var server = https.createServer(options, function (request, response) {
    response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/bold'});
    response.end("Server is running");
});
```

Now I want to connect a client to it, using a httprequest. I tried JQuery/XMLhttpRequest but I get Cross-origin resource sharing errors (which I get why but I think I don't really want to disable this protection). I think it's possible to use sockets to establish the connection but I'm not sure if that would be a good choice. I'd rather want to work with HTTP requests.

```
var xmlhttp, text;
xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open('GET', 'http://localhost/file.txt', true);
xmlhttp.send();

//JQuery get
$.get("http://127.0.0.1:1337")
```

Anything missing? Feel free to ask.

Comment: Do you get the Javascript/HTML from a different url than the node process that you want to send to?

Comment: @YaManicKill, The HTML I want to get is file.txt (should be an html file) And I think the client and server reside on different domains because of the given error, launched in two different CMD's/Terminals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change  `http://` to `https://` in your second set of code. Same-origin includes scheme/protocol. (And your server code appears to only be spinning up an `https` listener anyway. :) ).

Comment: Changed that to https, but still "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource." Ran server from CMD and opened client html in browser. I'm going to try to host it via node.js ..

Comment: "opened client html in browser" -- are you serving your client-side code to the browser using the same node.js process? or are you opening it as a local file on the machine -- ie `file:///` ?

Comment: I found the book "The Node Beginner" to be useful when I was first learning Node. You might check it out and see what you think.

Comment: Client side code is served to the browser using the same node.js process now. So NOW the requests seem to work. Before it was opened locally I think so it was ´hosted´ by a different process.

Might check out that book as well!

Answer (score 0):

Just a hint : If your client application page which is taking to your server is not rendered from the same domain where your server component is running then you will get such errors. This error means your page is going to access resources from another server, not from the server it is originated. All the browsers have such restriction. You can configure on you server to allow access form other domains (domain where your client app is hosted) or host both client app and server from same domain.

Comment: Configure so the server allows access from other domains is not recommended. Hosting both client app and server from the same domain, how would one achieve that?

Comment: Then host your html app from node itself , render them as static. https://github.com/expressjs/serve-static#serve-files-with-vanilla-nodejs-http-server

Comment: But the client should not be in Node.js. Or does this only let the client.html file be hosted by Node.js? I'm quite unexperienced server side so elaborating would help a lot.

Comment: If you want to stick to your point "Configure so the server allows access from other domains is not recommended", then quick option is host your html files through the same node.js (here node will work just as a simple html server) So in this case you can solve the issue of cross domain access.

Comment: If you want a separate http server to host your html/js files then in that case you have to put the proxy server in front of both the servers (node and ur http server hosting html pages) , browser should access those servers through proxy , giving an impression that both the node app and html app hosted in same domain. Hope it will help you.

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong. My assumption is that your client app is a HTML/JS app. If you own node, then there should not be any issue with hosting the HTML/JS files through node.js as well.

Comment: Hold on, I can host html/js files on the node.js server and just display them to the "client pc". Then via the browser I can make http requests (for example if a button is clicken or a certain url is put in) Right?